# Visual Studio project for Javascript,HTML and CSS website with debugging

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, debugging

I'm developling a pure front-end based application in the webbrowser. What I'm using is Javascript (jQuery, Knockout), HTML, CSS (bootstrap). So there is no backend, there is no need for it. In that respect, I can't find a proper project template in Visual Studio (up to 2017). All I can find is either ASP.NET MVC, or Javascript Window Apps. I think those project don't match my goal. I do only want javascript, but not targeting the windows platform, but the browser. I do want a web project, but I do not require ASP.Net.

What I have so far is a blank solution, add existing project, selected the root folder. All files are there in a web project which can be launched via Visual Studio. But I can not debug javascript code this way. Or I do not know how.

So the question is, is there any matching project template I can use, or how do I debug the javascript code?

Comment: Why the need for Visual Studio? You can use Visual Studio Code for simple projects. It also has nice debugging tools, but if it's pure frontend code, you can actually just debug in your browser's developer tools.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry, but not just simple Javascript. You can create empty ASP.Net Web site and use it for HTML, CSS, and JavaScript programming. The Webconfig file provided by ASP.NET enables debugging in Visual Studio (or you can use F12 tools when you run the app).

Answer (score 0):

You can create an empty ASP.Net Web site and use it for HTML, CSS, and JavaScript programming.

Actually VS2017 also has the new feature debug the JavaScript.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2016/11/21/client-side-debugging-of-asp-net-projects-in-google-chrome/