# Visual Studio project for Javascript, HTML website with debugging

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, visual-studio

I want to play with javascript and html and a bit more and would like to do so in Visual Studio. There is a very similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46360860/visual-studio-project-for-javascript-html-and-css-website-with-debugging). The solution says I can can create an empty ASP.Net Web site and use that. But I can't find a project template for an 'empty ASP.Net Web site'. The closest I get is 'ASP.net core empty project' and that uses c# and I can't see how to get my html and javascript involved. How can I get this 'empty ASP.Net Web site' or how can I use the 'ASP.net core empty project'?

Comment: check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/58239052/5334486

Comment: whoo! That worked and I've nearly got javascript debugging to work. Thanks!

Comment: alright then, I'm going to flag this as a duplicate

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create an ASP.NET website in Visual Studio 2019?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58224003/how-to-create-an-asp-net-website-in-visual-studio-2019)

Comment: Yes, also useful, but I found all that easily after I had used your first comment and been to https://stackoverflow.com/a/58239052/5334486. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

As GrafiCode said. Create an empty ASP.Net website.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uulYa.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Vs98.png)

The image above shows how to create an empty ASP.Net website. Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 1):

In VS 2022 empty ASP project will create following `Porgram.cs`:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
var app = builder.Build();

app.MapGet("/", () => "Hello World!");

app.Run();
```

To run simple `index.html` page change this file to this:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
var app = builder.Build();

app.UseDefaultFiles();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.Run();
```

Then create a `wwwroot` folder directly inside the project and put the `index.html` in this folder.

I've found above steps in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vzilt47V5GY)

Answer (score 0):

ASP.Net always represents the backend, where your data come from and in "Views" you can just create normal html pages and of cause you can use Java script in there.

HomeController

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}
```

And in Views you have a Index file in "Home". There you can start with your page, but data only comes from the C# code if you need data from the database.

But my recommendation would be, if you just want to use html and javascript. Install VS Code and javascript via nvm and create a file index.html.

Comment: What are views? At the moment I am just using the Chrome debugger, but I might want to go on to typescript.

Comment: @GeorgeKeeling Did you figure it out? I created empty ASP project. The server is starting and works properly but I don't see any "Views". Where do I put my Index.html and content files? I have an Installers libraries in C# and C# program that uploads installers through ftp and stores info in json files. I've wrote  a simple page which read those files and displays list of installers that an user can download. This all works without a server-side code, without issues, but I just want to put this page in my Installers C# solution as I currently have this page on desktop :P

Comment: @pawcio yes I did figure it out as shown by my "whoo!" comment on Sep 3, 2022 at the top